# How to resize(crop) images when changing from desk top to mobile

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using twitter-bootstrap with my rails application and as such I'm designing for desktop and mobile at the same time.

On desktop my site uses a series of "banner" style images that fit perfectly. When viewed in mobile these images keep their scaling and as such are just too small.

What I would like to happen is something very similar to what happens to a user profile in the facebook application. When you view your facebook profile on desktop your banner image is its original size where as when your profile is viewed in mobile the left and right sides are cropped off.

Is it possible to do this without uploading 2 sets of image?

Is there something I have overlooked in bootstrap or something basic in css that I can use to fix this?

As an example my banner picture looks like this in desktop
[image: desktop fb banner]

And in mobile it looks like this

[image: mobile fb banner]

I would really like to apply this functionality to my own site as it switches between mobile and desktop, any help is very much appreciated

Edit 1

here is a sample of the html I'm using to display an image

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
      <div class="home-about-us">
        <%= image_tag("about_us.jpg")%>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the sass that I have applied to my application

```
.home-about-us{
     img{
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
     }
 }
```

Comment: give `width:100%` to image

Comment: that does not crop the edges off

Comment: @arg0 ahhh A big Sorry for not reading your question completely.
You need to remove `max-width` from your `img`. And We can only solve the query if we are given with some code or link where we can see the issue. Once again SORRY

Comment: Yeah I thought the question might be misinterpreted, it is kind of a strange one since normally people want to keep scaling and the entire image between mobile and desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of two things:

1) Set a max-width restriction on the img so that it can only be as wide as the device itself, or,

2) Use a media query which specifiesg the max-width as 720 for mobiles, and then specify the width of the image, and then create another media query but this time using a min-width of 720 for tablets and desktops, specifying a different width for the image.

Comment: both of these solutions will keep scaling or resize the image without cutting the sides off and that's not what I want. sorry

Comment: I've previously done this with heights by setting them as specific pixel heights rather than percentages. Are you able to successfully achieve the same by specifying the width as px rather than a %?

Comment: using specific px sizes will remove allot of the dynamic design that I have gained from using bootstrap.
currently I'm rewriting the html with new image files that only run in mobile.

Comment: Understood. Sorry i couldn't be of more help

Answer (score 0):

Just use the BS responsive image class ("img-responsive") - see [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images) straight from the BS site.

Comment: image-responsive class doesn't exist in twitter-bootstrap-rails(2.2.8) gem